# Problems pushing a new repo to Synology git server

Tags: git, synology

I have recently set up git on a Synology NAS (DS2220j if that makes any difference) and have successfully set up things like using public keys etc, and can push updates to a repository that exists on the Synology server itself.

My setup is that my own user on the Synology drive has a git directory in its home directory. I run the following to create a repo:

```sh
ssh user@NAS
cd git
git init --bare repo.git
```

I can then run locally

```
cd repo
git remote add origin user@NAS:git/repo.git
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

and this will push my repo to the git server fine. My problem is that I want to be able to skip the initial step where I ssh into the Synology drive, as I don't actually want to be able to directly ssh into an interactive shell as my user. If I skip this step however, I get the following output:

```
fatal: 'git/repo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

On some git servers there is a line in the config to allow pushing fresh repos, but I can't see any documentation for the server included in the Synology package centre (which is what I'm using) and various tutorials show it just working. One tutorial showed creating a bare `_template.git` in the folder where you wish to push repos, which I've tried, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Git itself *cannot* create a new repository on its own like this, so any server that can has to be doing that by noticing that there isn't a repository yet and not running the normal push receiving software *yet* but instead first running any `mkdir`s needed (if necessary/allowed) and then running an appropriate `git init --bare`. So this would definitely require something special on the Synology side.

Comment: @torek Sure, this is something that would be the responsibility of the git server package. With gitolite, for example, you can make a user a CREATOR and then allow them to push any repo that matches a regex whether it already exists or not. Pushing new repos to a path your user can write to is shown to 'just work' in many Synology git tutorials, which is why I'm using the user's own home directory, and why I'm asking how I may have misconfigured something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can completely control what a user/key combo is allowed to do by setting up that user's `~/.ssh/authorized-keys` file for that key. Put

```
command="bin/checkcommand" ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NklC1wZDI1NTE5AAAAIH5NBbarfcodeFWkCC6KKU8qYLBNpnYWXHpxwcTKBesu you@example.com
```

in it and whenever you sign on as that user with that key their `bin/checkcommand` will run with `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` set to whatever was on the `ssh` command line, so you'll have to basically do some simple command parsing to permit even`git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack` if you want them able to fetch or push.

Say `man sshd` and search for `command=` for the starter kit I'm cribbing from, I haven't checked but I'd bet money gitolite and so on use exactly this mechanism.

`bin/checkcommand` might look a little like this, but with a whitelist of commands it will run, rather than running whatever you throw at it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e
set -o pipefail;

echo command="${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}" >> ~/.ssh/log; 

# Up to the first space is the command
case $(echo "${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}" | cut -f 1 -d ' ') in
    "git-receive-pack" | "git-upload-pack")
        # Second part is the git directory, contained within quotes
        GITDIR="$( \
            echo "${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}" \
                | cut -f 2- -d " " \
                | cut -f 2 -d "'" \
        )";
        echo "git at ${GITDIR}" >> ~/.ssh/log;

        if [ ! -d ${GITDIR} ]; then
            git init --bare ${GITDIR} 2>&1 >> ~/.ssh/log;
        fi
    ;;  
esac

bash -c "${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}" | tee -a ~/.ssh/log;
```

Comment: This is a nice hint towards an answer, but it's not really enough to solve the issue for the average drive-by user. I'll try and have a look into this soon and if I can find a simple easy of getting our to work, I'll update and accept, but if you have any more to add, it would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't really said how you want it to work, which makes it hard to say what goes in ~thatuser/bin/checkcommand.  For instance: it'd be pretty easy to set up a linux user so `newrepo reponame` made a new repo with that name on the nas, by setting up newrepo as an alias for `ssh thenas` and `thenas` in `.ssh/config` with the user, host and key combo you've set up to drive that checkcommand. Dedicate a key to the repo-creation and nothing else even has to know this setup exists at all.

Comment: I thought I had, possibly rather too implicitly. When you attempt to push a repo that doesn't exist then it does the necessary `git init --bare` and then processes the push command as per usual.

Comment: To add a little more explanation: I think it's fine to assume some scripting knowledge, but few people know exactly what commands are sent over ssh when you do a git push. I certainly don't without referencing manpages while I do so, and making multiple mistakes before I get it right ;)

Comment: Ah. Okay. I can see that in your question now, create-by-pushing was just such a foreign idea to me I needed a little more explicit, uh, push? . . . anyway, that would require frontending `git-receive-pack` on the server. So you could use the `command=` firewall on every connection, and have it notice when a requested `git-receive-pack` is referencing a non-existent repo, then init it before exec'ing the command.

Comment: I have suggested an edit - let me know if you're happy with it being on your answer, and I'll accept it. OR you can make it a community wiki or whatever.

Comment: Community wiki was a good suggestion, thanks. The whole auto-create notion bothers me, some fine morning when you can't remember how spell an existing repo name to save your life you're going to make a hell of a mess that way, but the mechanism itself is general.